# Video in media players appears on top of everything else

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc, smplayer

I thought this was just a VLC problem, so I installed SMPlayer and the same thing happens. The video just appears over top of *everything else*; other windows, menus, etc. I'm using 16.04. It never did this when I was using 14.04 or below.

I can't take screenshots because the video disappears when I hit print screen. (This behavior is also new.) So here are some cell phone photos:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuhiP.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/daZiO.png

How do I fix this?

(Edit for more information:) For whatever reason, Totem doesn't do this. I guess I'll be using it until I find a fix, but this isn't ideal since Totem handles subtitles pretty lousily.

Comment: Did not work this way on my system but have a look at the Video settings and uncheck 'Always on Top'. This might be enough to solve the issue....

Comment: It's already unchecked.

Comment: See [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1777925) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/770283). Apparently this is a bug which has been sitting there since 2011.

Comment: One user says they found a solution:

`I found the solution.

Unchecking /apps/metacity/general/capture_before_unmap in gconf-editor, logout and log back in solved this issue in my computer.`

After installing gconf-editor, the only things under /apps are... /gconf-editor and /aisleriot, weirdly enough. :(

(Sorry for the rapid edit spamming, my fingers keep wanting to hit enter for a new line.)

Comment: This solution worked for me . http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232444/vlc-media-player-window-is-overlaying-other-windows-in-ubuntu-14-04-compiz-win